# mysql in app feature is deactivated in my Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I have an app in azure and wanna to enable **"mysql in app"** feature inside it to use MySQL. I read many articles but they say we must enable it by clicking on "mysql in app" menu and toggle *on off* button.

But as you see in below picture this option is deactivated in my portal?

[image]

What is my mistake?? How can I activate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using a Linux-based Web App, MySQL in-app is not available for Linux App Service plans.

You could either create a Windows based Web App or use a Docker container to host both, your application and a MySQL database on Web Apps (see also [here](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/06/07/MySQL-in-app-feature-for-Web-Apps-on-Linux.html)).

Comment: Yes, I have a Linux web app. So I need to change it to windows. Thank you.